# Converting parent-child relationships in FK column into a hierarchical path string

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, hierarchical-data

I have a dataframe that keeps parent-child relationships between rows in a fk column called `parent_id`.

I want to convert this `dataframe` into a hierarchical data structure such as `data.tree` which is equivalent to a list of lists.

Here is my input `dataframe`:

```
df = data.frame(id = 1:3, name = c("asia", "iran", "tehran"), parent_id = c(NA, 1, 2))
df
# id,name,parent_id
# 1,asia,NA
# 2,iran,1
# 3,tehran,2
```

Here is the target output to convert the input into. Here I have added a new column called `pathString` which contains the hierarchical parent-child path of each row.

```
# target data:
#
# id,name,parent_id,pathString
# 1,asia,NA,asia
# 2,iran,1,asia/iran
# 3,tehran,2,asia/iran/tehran
```

How can I produce `pathString` column that contains the parent-child relationships in between rows?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
df$pathString=sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) paste(df[,2][1:i],  collapse = '/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `FromDataFrameNetwork` directly, e.g. something like this:

```
library(data.tree)
df <- data.frame(parent_id = c(0, 1, 2), id = 1:3, name2 = c("asia", "iran", "tehran"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

tree <- FromDataFrameNetwork(df)
tree$name2 <- "world"
tree$Do(function(x) x$id <- x$name)
tree$Do(function(x) x$name <- x$name2)

print(tree, "id")
```

This will print:

```
           levelName id
1 world               0
2  °--asia            1
3      °--iran        2
4          °--tehran  3
```